# Add enum values at class-loading time

Tags: java, enums

Articles such as [this one](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html) discuss how to create a new instance of an Enum class at runtime, for the purpose of testing forward compatibility (e.g. an otherwise-unreachable `default` branch of a `switch`). It seems to me that a better time to do so would be at class-loading time, to avoid breaking things like `EnumMap<>`. This would also be the time to do it in production code when dealing with an out-of-date enum from a legacy jar. What's the easiest way to add instances to an enum class during loading while maintaining the enum invariants?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Java Agent during class loading time [Guide to Java instrumentation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation)

Comment: please add code snippets instead of link as link may not work in future.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: it doesn't explain how to add new enum values to an existing class file in Javassist.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BeanShell or Groovy for this purpose. 
Groovy doc: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html

Comment: There's no mention of enums at that link.